# How do I get the number of rows in a query using ucanaccess

Tags: java, jquery, database, ucanaccess

I am using ucanaccess to connect java with access database.
I am using this code to count the number of rows in a query:

```
ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
int size;
rs.last();
size = rs.getRow();
```

but it shows this Exception

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: feature not supported
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.last(UcanaccessResultSet.java:903)
```

Is there is another way to get the number of rows in ucanaccess ?....

Answer (score 1):

Your resultset isn't scrollable. 
You should use:

```
Statement stat = super.ucanaccess.createStatement(
                         ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                        ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY
                        );
```

in order to invoke rs.last();

Your question is misplaced. Please refer to the official JDBC documentation.